# Reading XML returned from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have defined this XML file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<town>
   <area>20000</area>
   <population>10000</population>
</town>
</root>
```

with AJAX I load this and I try to parse it.

```html
<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
 myFunctionParsing(this);
}};

xhttp.open("GET", "towns.xml", false);
xhttp.send();

function myFunctionParsing(xml)
{
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("town");   
  var n = nodes[0].childNodes[0];    
  console.log(n.tagName);
  var aDiv = document.getElementById("area");
  aDiv.innerHTML = n.nodeValue;
}
```

With that script I want to write in div value of node "area" in some div with name "area".

Why can not I write this value? Why n.tagName is undefined?

Comment: `.childNodes` include **text** nodes such as `\n`. Try to use `children` or `nodes[0].getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

- I am using MDN's [XMLHttpRequest example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML), which shows how to override the mime type to force it to parse the response as XML. That way you don't have to do `responseXML`.
- `querySelector` is great! Use it. No need for `getElementsByTagName`.

```js
function parseXML(xml) {

 var area = xml.querySelector('town area');
 console.log(area.textContent); // => 20000

}

var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gabrielflorit/c618f26ac367fbaf91846efe73913c23/raw/b3c9c3e8d0f1dc747006103442b3b19bf7c91d9c/town.xml';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);

// If specified, responseType must be empty string or "document"
xhr.responseType = 'document';

// overrideMimeType() can be used to force the response to be parsed as XML
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

xhr.onload = function () {
 if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
   parseXML(xhr.response);
  }
 }
};

xhr.send(null);
```